# Latest updates cause auto print debug statements without requesting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just updated my environment to be the newest and getting strange messages for normal usage. Utilizing packages results in debug statements being thrown without requesting this.

Google is not revealing anything.  Surely someone has seen this before. How can I prevent this?
I can try and post my package environment if that would help.  I am on python 3.9.10.

Example when using yahoo_fin:

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info
df = stock_info.get_data('msft', interval='1d')

[D:urllib3.connectionpool] Starting new HTTPS connection (%d): %s:%s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
```

Example when using matplotlib (if using negatives in a log plot, which an error is expected):

```
[D:matplotlib.ticker] vmin %s vmax %s
[D:matplotlib.ticker] ticklocs %r
```

Comment: Where exactly are you running your code and seeing these messages?

Comment: It occurs in the basic terminal or IDEs.

Comment: Running in a venv environment, although I assume that doesnt matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to delete the entire python environment and start from scratch ensuring that every single package was the latest (I last updated about 1 month ago).

Looks like these random messages issue have entirely disappeared. I guess if anyone else has this problem, try redoing the entire environment.